# Scanner.nextLine() isn't reading the text in my file

Tags: java, file-io

I have a Java program that's supposed to read all of the lines of text in a .txt file using Scanner.nextLine():

```
//currLine is an instance variable storing the most recently read line.
//headerLine is a String being built.

//Precondition: There is a line break some time after, represented as an 
//empty String, "".

while (currLine.matches(".*: .*") ){
        headerLine = currLine;
        currLine = scanner.nextLine();
        while (!currLine.matches(".*: .*") && !currLine.matches("") ) {
            headerLine += currLine;
            currLine = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        headerLines.add(headerLine);
}
```

It works for a while, until it reaches this specific line:

```
"Received: from 64.117.6.245 by ; Mon, 20 Feb 2006 10:36:00 -0400
Message-ID: <HRDYTIFYZIKHQYPRQHEP@hanmail.net>"
```

Using a debugger in *two different IDE's*, I find that the program will read:

```
"Received: from 64.117.6.245 by ; Mon"
```

but not the rest of the line. Instead I'll get a NoSuchElementException, even though there's clearly more text, not just in that line, but also in the rest of the file.

Does anybody know why this is happening and what I should do?

Comment: What system are you on? Windows and linux have different line terminators. What line terminators does your text file have?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS right now.

Comment: What condition are you using to terminate the loop that is reading the lines of text?  Some sample code would be helpful.

Comment: The loop-termination condition is in another part of the code, because I'm assuming that there's no end-of-file in this part of the code. There shouldn't be. There are more lines to go through =\

Comment: @danharel Not that it matters but `matches(".*: .*)` can be replaced with simple `contains(": ")`. Also instead of `matches("")` you can use `isEmpty()`.

Comment: My professor specifically wants us to use matches() to practice regex